# Why can I not see the default gateway when connecting to ASA through AnyConnect?

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, sslvpn, cisco-anyconnect

I've configured an ASA as an AnyConnect server. The IP address pool that'll be assigned to the connecting hosts is from 192.168.10.1-192.168.10.10. Now when I establish a remote access connection to the ASA, the host gets an IP of 192.168.10.1 and the ipconfig command says it has no default gateway. The route print command shows "on-link" for the traffic (Secured route is 0.0.0./0).

On the other hand, when I set the address pool range from 192.168.10.2-192.168.10.10 I can see the default gateway as 192.168.10.1 (the assigned IP is 192.168.10.2) which is the expected behavior.

Can someone explain this anomaly?

Comment: If the ASA is 10.1, *you* can't be 10.1 as well.

Comment: That's not an anomaly. The only oddity is that the ASA wasn't smart enough to not hand out its own IP address as part of the pool, or stop you from including its IP address when you defined the pool. Since you can't have two hosts with the same IP address, your non-working behaviour is expected. When you changed your pool to start with .2, you corrected your mistake.